# Symfony2 form Entity choice type

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a entity Product and when I want to use a list of products in a form I use

```
->add('products', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => "Produit : ",
                    'class' => 'XXXCommonBundle:Product',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)  {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                            ->orderBy('p.title', 'ASC');
                    },
                    'property' => 'title',
                    'required' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true));
```

When I add this I have a list of checkbox with my product. But the problem that I should have a list with check box Picture of product (with `<img />` tag), the title and the price. My list should be in a form.

Answer (score 0):

You want to customize/theme your form field. Take a look at the cookbook article on [form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).